# create object a random number of times ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, random

```
def pass_growing_season
 self.age += 1
 if self.age >= 6
   harvested_oranges << Orange.new   #NEED 100 - 300 !!!
 end
 if self.height < 25
   self.height += 2.5
 end
end
```

I am trying to initialize an Orange class that is defined in another file.  Right now I have one new object getting shoveled into an empty array.  I want to create a random number them between 100 and 300.  So far I have tried

```
harvested_oranges = Orange.new(rand(100.300))
```

but I get an error telling me the Orange.new is taking an argument and isn't supposed to... must not be the right plan... any help would be great!

Comment: Here the argument for [Kernel#rand](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) is intended to be a range: `rand(100..300) #=> 156`. Ranges, instances of the class [Range](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Range.html) are defined with two dots (inclusive of end value) or three dots (exclusive of end value).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

`harvested_oranges = Array.new(rand(100..300)) { Orange.new }`

Comment: awesome.  thanks.  that's what I was looking for.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create a random number and store that in a variable.  Then use that variable in a for loop where you keep doing the `harvested_oranges << Orange.new` thing each time the loop runs.